# why python scrapy is showing "twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError" error

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a page using python scrapy . After some scrapping operation scrapy is quitting showing

```
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError error
```

Here is my code:

```
#infobel_spider.py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from infobel.items import InfobelItem
import sys
import xlwt
import re
import codecs    

class InfobelSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'infobel'
    start_urls = ['http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories']

    def parse(self,response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        next_page = hxs.select("//a[@id='Pagination1_lnkNextRec']/@href").extract()
        if not not next_page:
             yield Request("http://www.infobel.com"+next_page[0],self.parse)

        qs = hxs.select("//div[@class='result-item clearfix']")
        items = []
        for q in qs:
            item = InfobelItem()
            item['name'] = q.select('div/div/h2/a/span/text()').extract()
            item['address'] = q.select('div/div/ul/li[1]/div/span/text()').extract()
            item['phone'] = q.select('div/div/ul/li[2]/div/text()').extract()
            item['email'] = q.select('div/div/ul/li[3]/div/a/text()').extract()
            item['website'] = q.select('div/div/ul/li[4]/div/a/@href').extract()
            item['category'] = q.select("div/div[@class='categories']/div/ul/li/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item

#items.py    
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class InfobelItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    name = Field()
    address = Field()
    phone = Field()
    email = Field()
    category = Field()
    website = Field()

#middlewares.py    
import base64
import random
from settings import PROXIES

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        proxy = random.choice(PROXIES)
        if proxy['user_pass'] is not None:
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
            encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy['user_pass'])
            request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
        else:
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']

#pipelines.py
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
import re
import json
import csv

class InfobelPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = csv.writer(open('items.csv','wb'))
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        name = item['name']
        address = item['address']
        phone = item['phone']
        email = item['email']
        category = item['category']
        website = item['website']
        self.file.writerow((name,address,phone,email,category,website))
        return item

#settings.py    
BOT_NAME = 'infobel'
BOT_VERSION = '1.0'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['infobel.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'infobel.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'infobel.items.InfobelItem'
USER_AGENT = '%s/%s' % (BOT_NAME, BOT_VERSION)
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['infobel.pipelines.InfobelPipeline']
PROXIES = [{'ip_port': '41.43.31.226:8080', 'user_pass': ''},
           {'ip_port': '64.120.226.94:8080', 'user_pass': ''},
           {'ip_port': '196.2.73.246:3128', 'user_pass': ''},]
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'infobel.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[infobel] INFO: Passed InfobelItem(website=[u'track.aspx?id=0&url=http://www.bbmodena.it'], category=[u'TELEVISION, VIDEO AND HI-FI EMERGENCY BREAKDOWN SERVICES, REPAIRS AND SPARE PARTS'], name=[u'B &amp; B (S.R.L.) (RIP.TVC VIDEO HI-FI)'], phone=[u'059254545'], address=[u'V. MALAVOLTI\xa047', u'41100', u'MODENA'], email=[u'info@bbmodena.it'])
[infobel] DEBUG: Scraped InfobelItem(website=[u'track.aspx?id=0&url=http://sitoinlavorazione.seat.it/boninispa'], category=[u'AUTOMOBILE AGENTS, DEALERS AND DEALERSHIPS'], name=[u'BONINI (S.P.A.) (CONCESSIONARIA RENAULT)'], phone=[u'035310333'], address=[u'V. S. BERNARDINO\xa0151', u'24126', u'BERGAMO'], email=[u'info@boniniautospa.it']) in <http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories>
[infobel] INFO: Passed InfobelItem(website=[u'track.aspx?id=0&url=http://sitoinlavorazione.seat.it/boninispa'], category=[u'AUTOMOBILE AGENTS, DEALERS AND DEALERSHIPS'], name=[u'BONINI (S.P.A.) (CONCESSIONARIA RENAULT)'], phone=[u'035310333'], address=[u'V. S. BERNARDINO\xa0151', u'24126', u'BERGAMO'], email=[u'info@boniniautospa.it'])
[infobel] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories/10> (failed 1 times): 200 OK
[infobel] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories/10> (failed 2 times): 200 OK
[infobel] DEBUG: Discarding <GET http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories/10> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure.
[infobel] ERROR: Error downloading <http://www.infobel.com/en/italy/business/20300/accessories/10>: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError'>: User timeout caused connection failure.

[infobel] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[infobel] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: It would likely be helpful if you would post your code, at least we could see whether the error was with you or with the site.

Comment: I have added delay ... And its working fine now

Comment: Hey. Looks like you found a solution to your problem. You should add the solution here as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found this question having the same problem. The user asking has solved his on his own, I'm posting it here so it is more visible:

Setting a delay between downloading pages from a site can help with timeout errors resulting from too frequent requests to it. This is done via the DOWNLOAD_DELAY parameter in the project's settings.py file.

[The Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY) has this to say:

> The amount of time (in secs) that the downloader should wait before
> downloading consecutive pages from the same website. This can be used
> to throttle the crawling speed to avoid hitting servers too hard.
> Decimal numbers are supported. Example:
>
> DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25    # 250 ms of delay

## Update from comment

In addition to DOWNLOAD_DELAY, if the RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting parameter is True, Scrapy will sample a delay a factor of 0.5 to 1.5 of the DOWNLOAD_DELAY. Their documentation adds

> This randomization decreases the chance of the crawler being detected
> (and subsequently blocked) by sites which analyze requests looking for
> statistically significant similarities in the time between their
> requests.

Note that RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY is True by default.

Comment: In 2020 the [RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY) is usually a more effective method to avoid timeout delays and temp bans.